# Getting a logical error while running following code

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

```py
from decimal import Decimal
n = int(input())
student_marks = {}
for _ in range(n):
    name, *line = input().split()
    scores = list(map(float, line))
    student_marks[name] = scores
query_name = input()
avg = Decimal(sum(scores)/3)
avg = round(avg, 2)
print(avg)
```

**Input:**

```
2
Harsh 25 26.5 28
Anurag 26 28 30
Harsh
```

**Expected Output**

```
26.50
```

**My Output**

```
28.00
```

The provided code stub will read in a dictionary containing key/value pairs of name:[marks] for a list of students. Print the average of the marks array for the student name provided, showing 2 places after the decimal.

The first line contains the integer n, the number of students' records. The next n lines contain the names and marks obtained by a student, each value separated by a space. The final line contains query_name, the name of a student to query.

**Input**

```
3
Krishna 67 68 69
Arjun 70 98 63
Malika 52 56 60
Malika
```

**My Output**

```
56.00
```

**Expected Output**

```
56.00
```

My code works for this input but doesn't work for another input. Could you please try to explain why?

Answer (score 2):

In your case, you are not using the query correctly.
while calculating avg you are always calculating avg score of the last person.

```py
avg = Decimal(sum(scores)/3)
```

correct way will be something like this:

```py
avg = Decimal(sum(student_marks[query_name])/3)
```